# dynamic options in an MVC website

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a MVC web site that has a Product details view.
On this view are a number of details about the product.

What i need is to ask the user a number of questions before they add the item to their cart.
for example what colour, what size, QTY.... but not all products have the same list of options.
Some options will have a dropdown list others will be free text field.
What is the best way to build this section of the page? it feels like i need a xml field in the product table that holds product specific xml that can be parsed into the options section of this page. But i dont know if that is even possible or how i would save the data.

If you have any ideas as to the best solution i would be very grateful !!

Thanks
John

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply.

To start off, have a look at [template folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308450%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)s in MVC, you get two types DisplayTemplates and EditorTemplates.

Now they work the same as a normal view, but live in special folders, named the same as above for example.

```
\Views\Home\Index.cshtml  
\Views\Home\DisplayTemplates\MyViewModelName.cshtml
\Views\Home\EditorTemplates\MyViewModelName.cshtml
```

This is how they work.

If you create your `ProductDetailsViewModel` like this:

```
public class ProductDetailsViewModel {
     public IList<Question> Questions { get;set; }
}
```

A `Question` can be an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class Question {
 // .. maybe need some common properties here, like answer value?
}
```

Then you can define more specific questions like:

```
public class TextQuestion : Question {

}

public class RadioQuestion : Question {

 // maybe has a list of options for display etc.

}
```

And so on.

Then lets say using the above structure in you \Home\Index.cshtml view you could simply do the following.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
     <p>Put your form here</p>

     @Html.TextboxFor(x=>x.ProductName)

     @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

What will happen next is MAGIC, for each actual type `TextQuestion`, `RadioQuestion` it will look for the corresponding partial view in EditTemplate and render it as appropriate.

So if we have \Home\EditorTemplates\RadioQuestion.cshtml defined as:

```
@model RadioQuestion

<p>This is a radio button based question</p>

// Implement the radio buttons or text boxes etc here.
```

Of course display works in the same way.